# How to assume a number to be a half integer?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

For integer `x` $\left(\cos 2\pi x\right) ^2=1$ and I can check this as follows

```
Simplify[Cos[2 \[Pi] x]^2, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Integers]
```

and get `1` as an output. The same holds when `x` is half-integer. How do I assume this in `Mathematica`? More generally, is there a nice way to implement assumptions of the type say $x\in 3\mathbb{Z}+2$ without redefining variables that I use?

Comment: Try `Simplify[Cos[2 π x]^2, x + 1/2 ∈ Integers]` and report back.

Comment: `Simplify[Cos[2 π x]^2 /. x -> 3 k + 2, k ∈ Integers]`

Comment: `Simplify[Cos[2 π x]^2, (x - 2)/3 ∈ Integers]`